# Extract public key from certificate

Tags: c#, cryptography, crt

Is there a way to extract the public key from a certificate using C#? I have a certificate file with .crt extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
certificate = new X509Certificate2("server.crt", "secret_password");
byte[] publicKey = certificate.PublicKey.EncodedKeyValue.RawData;
```

now the 'publicKey' byte array is the ASN.1-encoded representation of the public key value.

Comment: `byte[] publicKey = certificate.GetPublicKey.EncodedKeyValue.RawData;` didnt work for me, had to use just `byte[] publicKey = certificate.GetPublicKey();`

Comment: well yes, that's more suitable if you're going to make use of the public key directly.

Comment: And how to get public key from bytes? for example, I have public key (generated with EC algorithm, curve "secp256r1") and its encoded bytes on java, How can I create public key from these bytes in c#?

Comment: For what I can see, the _public key info_ you get is actually a `sequence`, which contains among the rest the actual public key. See https://github.com/ajanicij/x509-tutorial/blob/master/x509-analysis.md